# Saving and fetching DateTime values

Tags: 2013, development, timezone

I have now confused myself how the SharePoint SPListItem DateTime field values should be set and fetched. I'm doing comparison of the dates, and running into issues probably due to me doing double Utc conversion. I know SP stores everything in UTC, but should I pass in the values as UTC, or not?

1. When I store datetime to field using C# like `listItem["MyDateField"] = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(myTime);`, should I pass in `myTime` as UTC, or should I pass it in timezone of the region of the site, so that SP can do the UTC conversion before storing it in DB?
2. When fetching this same datetime field using `var myDate = listItem["MyDateField"]` (in Timer Job), am I getting the datetime in UTC, or is it already converted to some user/server time zone?
3. Related to 1. is SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime actually already doing some time zone conversion already? So if I do `listItem["MyDateField"] = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);`, I will end up having incorrect time in DB?

Thanks!